# Create Droppable file link in Windows from QTableWidget row/cell Drag

Tags: c++, windows, qt, drag-and-drop

I would like to allow the user to drag a file path from a [`QTableWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) cell and drop this in a file manager (e.g. Windows Explorer) to create a link ([Windows file shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows)). 
I assume this requires modifying the dragged object data in place?

To start with, I have tried subclassing `QTableWidget` to reimplement the events

```
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QEvent>

class tableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    tableWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~tableWidget();

protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
    void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
};
```

and "promoted" `QTableWidget` in Qt Designer to my `tableWidget` (be sure not to have the objectName identical to the class) and set `dragEnabled`to `true`.

However, the event handlers seem not to be executed.
So I thought I might be looking in the wrong place, but [`QTableWidgetItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html) does not appear to have Drag and Drop events implemented, although [its documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#details) says

> By default, items are enabled, editable, selectable, checkable, and can be used both as the source of a drag and drop operation and as a drop target.

What do I need to do in order to create this behaviour? Is it necessary to create a [`QDrag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#details) object manually as shown in [Drag and Drop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html#dragging)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: Yes - it seems that [installing an object with `eventFilter` method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) allows handling the widget's `viewport()`'s `QMouseEvent`'s, where a QDrag object is set up according to the documentation linked in the question.

Then use

```
QTableWidgetItem *twi = ui->tWidget->itemAt( mouseEvent->pos() );
QString dirname( twi->text() );
```

to retrieve the dragged table cell data

However, passing the link file contents in QDrag object MIME data does not seem to work, as also noted [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/56644/implement-drag-and-drop-to-file-browser-or-desktop). Instead, passing the url ("file:///...") of an existing .lnk file works with Windows Explorer.
This does not really make a difference, as the link file needs to be created with e.g. `QFile::link()` anyway. Remove it after operation is completed.

While several Mime data segments can be passed (see Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\widgets\draganddrop\dropsite) I have not yet figured out what the order of preference is - e.g. the target application uses either the plain text target path *or* the reference url to the link file.

When using right mouse button for a drag-n-drop action, a context menu will be shown on release, depending on the DropActions specified as *supportedActions* in `exec()`. The dropAction returned by exec then might also be `TargetMoveAction` and `IgnoreAction`. Not sure if the context menu can be disabled.